# Remote ejb call with parameter

Tags: java, serialization, ejb

I have ejb with method

```
void create(A a);
```

and class B which extends class A.

i tried call ejb from client server

```
...
B b = getB();
...

bean.create(new A()); // OK

bean.create(new B()); // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (class B is defined just on client server)

bean.create(b); // No EJB receiver available for handling ...
```

i have two questions:

- what is difference between second and third call ? why i get different errors?
- how can I call remote ejb with object of class B ?

Comment: Confuse question, can you please provide a more complete example of what you are doing? Creating a `new A()` just looks wrong - you never want to create an EJB on the client, you should just talk to the bean "living" on the server side using its remote interface.

Comment: i dont't want create EJB on the client, i try call ejb method create on server with parameter b.